# Jquery using undefined validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm using [jquery form validator](http://www.formvalidator.net/index.html#security-validators_backend) to validate some data on server side. my code is like

**HTML :**

```
<input data-validation="server" data-validation-url="/validate" name="vip_ip" type="text" id="vip_ip">
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/form.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/jquery.form-validator.min.js') }}"></script>
```

**Form.js** :

```
$(function($) {
$.validate({
    borderColorOnError: '',
    lang: 'fr'
});
```

This is the error that the validator throws on the console :

> Uncaught Error: Using undefined validator "validate_server"

I dont understand why the plugin adds this `validate` prefix. whice prevents the validation from working.
thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server Validation is in Security Module (Ref: http://www.formvalidator.net/index.html#security-validators_backend)

You need to enable the module by

```
$(function($) {
$.validate({
    modules : 'security',
    borderColorOnError: '',
    lang: 'fr'
});
```